# How to read userData in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, user-data

I need to pass `userData` to [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs), but can't find any examples of how to do this.  Here's my attempt:

Sent from the server:

```
{ total: 25,
  page: currentpage,
  userData: {foo: 'bar'},
  rows: myRows }
```

and in jqgrid:

```
var data = jQuery("#grid").getGridParam('userData');
```

How can I send `userData` and read it from jqgrid?

EDIT: I know my `userData` is being sent, because I can see it in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  I think I'm just stuck on how to read it on the client side.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general the usage of `userData` is pretty simple. jqGrid gives you support to send from the server any additional **data which will be saved together with the jqGrid data**. So if jqGrid parses the data returned from the server then it just looks for `userdata` (**not** for `userData`!!!) and save is in the internal parameter `userData`.

```
{ "total":25,
  "page":1
  "records":107,
  "userdata": {"foo": "bar"},
  "rows": [...] }
```

Be careful: the default property in the input data must be `userdata` and **NOT** `userData` like you currently have. You can overwrite the default name of input property `jsonReader: {userdata: "userData"}` or `jsonReader: {userdata: "myData"}` if you use `userData` or `myData` as the property name with your [additional data](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#user_data).

One from the standard usage of `userData` is for [displaying of the footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802036/what-is-the-jqgrid-footer-json-format/2821207#2821207) in the jqGrid. You can use the data for any your other propose. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564898/jqgrid-programatically-select-grid-row/3571392#3571392) it is shown how to use `userData` to select the some row/rows directly after the loading data from the server.

If you use `loadonce:true` parameter, the usage of `userData` will be a little more tricky because after the first load the data from the parameter `userData` will be deleted, so you have to save there in the external object.

Of cause you can access the `userData` with respect of `jQuery("#grid").getGridParam('userData')` only after the data are loaded. So you should do this inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle or later. By the way inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle you can access to **all** data which are send to you from the server through `data` parameter of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event. So you can read any other additional data and save there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. In case anyone reads this later, the summary is that when talking about a GridParam it's `userData`, otherwise it's `userdata`. Read `userdata` in the `loadComplete` event handler. To set `postData` with `userdata` do this: `loadComplete: function(data){jQuery("#ticketlist").setGridParam({ postData: { foo2: data.userdata.foo} });}`

Comment: @Slack: You can also use `jQuery("#grid").getGridParam('userData')` inside of `loadComplete` like `loadComplete: function(){jQuery("#ticketlist").setGridParam({ postData: { foo2: jQuery("#grid").getGridParam('userData').foo} });}`. It is only important to understand that in the data send from the server one have to place `userdata` and the data will be saved in `userData` parameter of jqGrid. So it can be accessible trough `getGridParam('userData')`. But the most important, that now your program works and can use `userdata`/`userData`. :-)

Comment: man I've been using userData instead of userdata in the json generator and I've been going crazy, thanks alot! +1

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid by default accepts JSON in this format.

```
{"rows":
    [{"foo":"bar"}]
}
```

and setting up the jqgrid options you would do something like this:

```
$("#cashflow-sheet").jqGrid({
    url:'bbc-json.html',
    datatype: "json",
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.  I actually have jqgrid working fine and can display rows without a problem.  I omitted that code.  What I don't understand is how to use jqgrid's `userData` feature.  This lets you send an array of user data from the server to the grid.