# Sending additional params in JSON string to jqGrid

Tags: php, json, jqgrid

I'm using PHP to generate JSON for JQGrid. I've added another property to the PHP object that I'm JSON encoding:

```
$sql_array = preg_split('/LIMIT/', $sql);
$pass_sql = $sql_array[0];
$response->sql = $pass_sql;
<~SNIP~>
echo json_encode($response);
```

This parses fine on the client side and populates the jqGrid with JSON like this:

```
{"page":"1","total":28,"records":"685","sql":"SELECT * FROM fires ORDER BY id desc ","rows":[{"id":"3065","cell":["Southern","Lost Fire","National Forests in Mississippi","492","100","0000-00-00",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"3065","2011-03-03 00:00:00"]},{"id":"3064","cell":["Southern","PineTree","East Central Area Dispatch Office","420","80","2011-03-02",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"3064","2011-03-03 00:00:00"]},{"id":"3063","cell":["Southern","LILAC ROAD","Georgia Forestry Commission","100","100","2011-03-01",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null //etc
```

I need to pull that sql param text out of the JSON reply and hide it in a DIV for later. Is this possible?

Comment: There may be some design issues here... but aside from that, you can do it in the handler that populates the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to send an additional information from the server to jqGrid is `userdata` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848815/how-to-read-userdata-in-jqgrid/3849513#3849513). If your JSON data will be like

```
{
    "page":"1",
    "total":28,
    "records":"685",
    "userdata":"SELECT * FROM fires ORDER BY id desc ",
    "rows":[
       ...
    ]
}
```

or

```
{
    "page":"1",
    "total":28,
    "records":"685",
    "userdata": {
        sql: "SELECT * FROM fires ORDER BY id desc "
    },
    "rows":[
       ...
    ]
}
```

The additional information will be saved inside of jqGrid and you can access of with `$("#grid_id").jqGrid('getGridParam','userData')`.

Be careful in the case of `userData`. In the JSON data it must be `userdata` and in the `getGridParam`: 'userData'.

Comment: FANTASTIC! I will give this a shot and mark this as "solved" as soon as I get in to work.